# Compare Previous column data with the next column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a sales table with the following columns. I want to select the rows where sale price is increasing and skip those decrease sale price in which the sale price of above row is increase. 
e.g. in the following table, I would like to have all rows except row having `saleid=4`

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| SaleId | ItemId | SalePrice |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 1      | 987    | 12        |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 2      | 678    | 13        |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 3      | 987    | 15        |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4      | 542    | 11        |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 5      | 678    | 16        |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

I have tried using inner join. But it shows nothing.
Here is the query I have wrote:

```
select s1.* from saletable s1
join saletable s2 on s1.saleid = s2.saleid
where s1.saleprice<s2.saleprice
```

Comment: Okay I did, it is actually MS Sql server, but I was looking for a generic algorithm

Comment: what if the last row has SalePrice = 14?

Comment: It should skip as saleid: 5 has a price of 16

Comment: no I mean what if the row with SaleId 5 has a SalePrice 14 instead of 16, should it be in the result? Note that in such case it has higher value than the preceding one ...

Comment: No, It will not include as the last largest value is 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution using running max

```
select t.*
from
(
    select *, max(SalePrice) over (order by SaleId) runningMaxSalePrice
    from testdata
) t
where t.SalePrice >= t.runningMaxSalePrice
```

This solution skips more than one consecutive row with decreasing SalePrice.

[DBFdiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d82dcccb079e7f1cba273ccddc9a3ffe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select st.*
from (select st.*, lag(saleprice) over (order by saleid ) as prev_saleprice
      from saletable st
     ) st
where prev_saleprice is null or saleprice > prev_saleprice
```

Comment: But it is skipping the rows like if I have 16 at multiple times at saleid:6, 7 and 8. It only shows one occurrence of 16 i.e. saleid:5

Comment: @MuhammadArslanJamshaid . . . Your question specifies "sale price is increasing".  If you want non-decreasing, then just replace `>` with `>=`.

Comment: Sorry, increasing or equal to, and I have used `>=` it includes 11 as well

Comment: I believe that the solution is not correct when there is more than one consecutive row bellow running max: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=129e367d185d8e68dd51b3fb18370e76